# Where is code location for website built with LocalWP

Tags: wordpress

I want to get the code of a wordpress site made with https://localwp.com/ LocalWP but I can't seem to find where it is. I want to upload website to my server. I know that I can use this software to move it on Live but I want the classic way to upload files and migrate DB, but I cannot find the code.

Anyone knows this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to open Local than right-click on site name and choose Open Site Shell:

[image: Open Site Shell]

You will be redirected to the terminal where you can see a path to the folder which you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I have the easiest way to get the code of WordPress

Right-click on the site and click on the **Go to site folder** it will open the explorer then go to the directory `app → public` here you will get the whole WordPress code.

[image]

For finding all the sites go to the directory `C:\Users\username\Local Sites`.

[image]

I hope it helps.